# Merge or delete learning & guide-related tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I'm referring to:

- [tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tutorial) x 67
- [learning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/learning) x 43
- [guide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guide) x 10
- [guidelines](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guidelines) x 7
- [troubleshooting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) x 739

Now, obviously they can all be merged (and if so we should also synonymize), but maybe they should be removed, I don't know.
Anyway, the only tag that is pretty much similar but seems more valid is [documentation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/documentation), but I don't know if it really suits all the questions in those tags.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/14448/how-do-you-teach-a-child-to-use-a-computer), for example, is only tagged with `[learning]` and I don't know what else it can be tagged with. I guess that's also why it was closed.

Comment: The only circumstance I can think of to keep "tutorial", "guide" and "guidelines" is a question about how to create a computer related tutorial. Tutorial then is a specific subset of documentation. Is there such a case that would be within the scope of superuser?

Answer (score 2):

The [troubleshooting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) tag serves a valid purpose and should be kept.  We need to make it clear that this tag be used for questions in which the OP is trying to diagnose a problem, rather than solve a known problem for which troubleshooting doesn't apply.

I would definitely agree with deleting the [guide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guide) and [guidelines](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guidelines) tag, though.  The [guide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/guide) tag doesn't convey much information, and a question which asks for guidelines is probably too subjective.  [learning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/learning) and [tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tutorial) look like meta-tags to me and probably should be deleted as well, but it isn't as clear a case as the other two tags.